# error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)()' to 'long unsigned int'

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm rather new to C++ and I'm trying to understand the code over on this forum http://www.blizzhackers.cc/viewtopic.php?p=2483118. I've managed to work out most of the errors but this one's got me stumped here's the code from the function giving me problems.

```
void LoadDll(char *procName, char *dllName)
{
    HMODULE hDll;
    unsigned long cbtProcAddr;

    hDll = LoadLibrary(dllName);
    cbtProcAddr = GetProcAddress(hDll, "CBTProc"); // The error points to this line

    SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, cbtProcAddr, hDll, GetTargetThreadIdFromProcname(procName));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the definition of `cbtProcAddr` to:

```
HOOKPROC cbtProcAddr;
```

The compiler is upset because you are trying to store a pointer-type value in an variable declared to hold an integer.  (You may need to cast the result of `GetProcAddress()` to `HOOKPROC`, since that function doesn't know the actual signature of the pointed-to function, but the usage of the pointer in the `SetWindowsHookEx()` call implies that it is compatible with the signature of the `HOOKPROC` function-pointer type.)

Comment: error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)()' to 'LRESULT (*)(int, WPARAM, LPARAM)' thats the error i get now is that from a different function?

Comment: I think the generic way of doing it (via a typedef) would be worth mentioning, too, as most function signatures don't have one.

Comment: @chris HOOKPROC *is* a typedef.

Comment: @user1241223 Try `cbtProcAddr = (HOOKPROC) GetProcAddress(hDll, "CBTProc");`

Comment: @cdhowie, I mean that this doesn't really help at all if using `GetProcAddress` is used for something else, without one. It's most likely the issue would come up in the future.

Comment: @cdhowie thanks that worked just a quick question what does putting the (HOOKPROC) in the declaration do?

Comment: @user1241223 It's not a declaration, it's a statement.  The expression `(type) expression` tells the compiler to convert `expression` to the type specified by `type`.  Two incompatible function pointers are not *implicitly* convertible, but they are *explicitly* convertible (using the cast expression makes the conversion explicit).

Comment: oh ok thanks for the clarification i'm still pretty new to C++ thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

[`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx) returns a `FARPROC` (which, looking at the compiler error, is just a typedef for `int(*)()`). `unsigned long` is not a `FARPROC`, and there's no implicit conversion between the two.

I can't fathom why you would store the result of `GetProcAddress` in an `unsigned long`. If you retrieve a function you want to store a function pointer. Use the correct type ([`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) takes a `HOOKPROC`) and cast:

```
HOOKPROC cbtProcAddr;

hDll = LoadLibrary(dllName);
cbtProcAddr = reinterpret_cast<HOOKPROC>(GetProcAddress(hDll, "CBTProc"));
```